# I would like to use dutch english russian and portugese in Pandora chatbots during the same session

Tags: aiml

We use pandorabots in Dutch and English and would like to use Portugese & Ukranian in same chatbot.

Comment: and what's your issue? Also, when you have a chance, take a look on it https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There's very little to go on here, but I answered something similar here if it's any use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69315355/is-there-a-way-to-add-multilingual-support-in-chatbot-using-pyaiml